# update using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php and mysql to update a column in the users table which is empty and only an admin can add the data but i am having a problem only numbers are being updated and not text.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET approved=?  WHERE id=?");
        $approved=$_POST['approved'];

        $sql->bind_param("id",$approved,$_GET["id"]);
        if($sql->execute()) {
            $success_message = "Edited Successfully";
        } else {
            $error_message = "Problem in Editing Record";
        }

    }
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?");
    $sql->bind_param("i",$_GET["id"]);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }
    $conn->close();
?>


<?php if(!empty($success_message)) { ?>
<div class="success message"><?php echo $success_message; ?></div>
<?php } if(!empty($error_message)) { ?>
<div class="error message"><?php echo $error_message; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<form  method="post" action="">
            <label>approved</label>
            <input type="text" name="approved" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $row["approved"]?>">
            <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit" class="demo-form-submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$approved` has a type of `String` then
You have an error in your bind parameter:

```
$sql->bind_param("id",$approved,$_GET["id"]);
```

Should be like this:

```
$sql->bind_param("si",$approved,$_GET["id"]); //s-- String, i--Integer
```

You can learn more on how to express variable type in `bind_param` using this link: [Binds variables to a prepared statement as parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)